# Postgresql To Return 0 when Null

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am attempting to run a query using `MAX()` but my issue is that if the field contains a `NULL` value the data returns nothing.  Updating the table is not an option, so how should this query be re-written to return 0 when `NULL`?

Sample DDL below - and I hardcoded a `WHERE` clause that returns nothing just for illustrative purposes, ideally I want to return all `usernames` and the highest `logincount` for the user

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
 username varchar(50) not null,
 logincount int,
 logindate Date
);

Insert Into Test (username, logincount, logindate) 
VALUES
('er11', 1, '2017-01-01'), ('er11', 2, '2017-01-02'), ('ff12', NULL, NULL)
,('jb88', 1, '2017-01-09');

With maxlogincount As
(
    select max(logincount) As "MaxLoginCount"
    ,username
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY username
)
Select
username
,logincount
,logindate
FROM Test t
inner join maxlogincount mlc
ON t.username = mlc.username
And mlc."MaxLoginCount" = t.logincount
WHERE t.username = 'ff12'
Order by t.username asc
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `max(coalesce(logincount, 0))` to avoid NULLs

According to [Postgres docs (9.6)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html):

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display, for example:

Comment: Where would I need to add the COALESCE()?  I tried to wrap it in the CTE - but still returns nothing

Comment: max(coalesce(logincount,0)) try it here: http://rextester.com/LSLFL11968

Comment: And all in a one-liner with no cte, very nice!

Comment: This will still return NULL if the no rows match the `WHERE` clause.  If that is not wanted, use coalesce(max(logincount),0) instead.

Comment: @jjanes do you mean table Test has no rows?

Comment: @jjanes because I applied it on the cte query that group by username.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I've missed something obvious here, but wouldn't the 
[NULLIF](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nullif/) function be a much better (and more elegant) solution?

Postgres documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html).

```
SELECT
  COUNT(NULLIF(logincount,0)) AS "Max Login Count",
  username,
FROM Test
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY "Max Login Count";
```

Result:

```
'Max Login Count'   username
----------------------------
               0        ff12
               1        jb88
               2        er11
```

Comment: NULLIF does (kind of) the opposite of COALESCE. It will return NULL when logicount is 0.

Comment: Insert Into Test (username, logincount, logindate) 
VALUES
('xyz', 0, NULL); - this produces a correct result - i.e. 'Max Login  Count' = 0 - or, again, have I missed something?

Comment: The sample data in the question are `('ff12', NULL, NULL)`. What does NULLIF give in that case?

Comment: It gives 0 as (I) expected.

Comment: Oh your code has COUNT and doesn't have MAX, I didn't notice that. It will work for these cases though. But count is different than MAX. I'm not if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: It gives the same result as the rextester snippet, but I just thought that it was more elegant?

Comment: If the logincount values go always 1,2,3,... yes. And I think a simpler `COUNT(logincount)` would give the same result, without NULLIF ;) But what if the values are 1,2,5,7? The MAX query  will give 7. Yours will give 4. So it depends on the actual values and constraints.